# Button onClick is not is not working in react displaying FindDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

this is what get doisplay in my console:
index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Tilt which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node
at div
at Tilt (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:36807:5)
at div
at Logo
at div
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:230:5)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable strict mode following these instructions: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

It is unlikely that this would be the source of your problem as it is just a warning, but I can't tell without looking at your code.

Comment: I read the Instructions but I did not grabs the meaning or what I should do. plscan u help?

Comment: Change  <React.StrictMode> to <React> in your app.js

Comment: I change the <React.StrictMode> to <React>, but the <React.StrictMode>, it's not in my app.js  rather it was found in index.js  but it still did not work.  hereis the code:

Comment: ReactDom.render(
  <React>
    <App />
  </React>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDom.render(
  <React>
    <App />
  </React>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);